# Editing preset schemes

Tags: plotting

*Mathematica* has many preset schemes, for example `"DarkRainbow"` and `"FadingRectangle"`:

```
Histogram[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, 0.2], 100], 
 ChartStyle -> "DarkRainbow", 
ChartElementFunction -> "FadingRectangle"]
```

[image: test]

How can I get *Mathematica* to tell me the source code for these schemes? I want to reproduce `"FadingRectangle"`, with some modifications of my own.

Comment: Try looking at the functions that show up after executing `?System\`BarFunctionDump\`*`.